# Create an S3 bucket with KMS encryption?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've been unsuccessful in locating a call that would allow me to create a KMS encrypted bucket in S3 (using the Java AWS SDK).

Does such a method exist?  And if so, where can I find examples/documentation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer.  The version of the AWS Java SDK I was using wasn't recent enough to have the method.

Here is how to do it:

```
    Bucket bucket =  amazonS3Client.createBucket( bucketName );
    ServerSideEncryptionRule serverSideEncryptionRule = new ServerSideEncryptionRule();

    ServerSideEncryptionByDefault serverSideEncryptionByDefault = new ServerSideEncryptionByDefault();
    serverSideEncryptionByDefault.setKMSMasterKeyID( "xxxxxxxxx-xxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxx" );
    serverSideEncryptionByDefault.setSSEAlgorithm( SSEAlgorithm.KMS.getAlgorithm() );

    serverSideEncryptionRule.setApplyServerSideEncryptionByDefault( serverSideEncryptionByDefault );

    SetBucketEncryptionRequest setBucketEncryptionRequest = new SetBucketEncryptionRequest();
    setBucketEncryptionRequest.setBucketName( bucket.getName() );

    ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration serverSideEncryptionConfiguration = new ServerSideEncryptionConfiguration();

    ArrayList< ServerSideEncryptionRule > serverSideEncryptionRules = new ArrayList<>();
    serverSideEncryptionRules.add( serverSideEncryptionRule );
    serverSideEncryptionConfiguration.setRules( serverSideEncryptionRules );

    setBucketEncryptionRequest.setServerSideEncryptionConfiguration( serverSideEncryptionConfiguration );

    amazonS3Client.setBucketEncryption( setBucketEncryptionRequest );
```

Answer (score 0):

[Have a look at this example](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/v1/developer-guide/examples-crypto-kms.html)

From that page, you could try something like this with the Java AWS SDK:

```
AmazonS3Encryption s3Encryption = AmazonS3EncryptionClientBuilder
        .standard()
        .withRegion(Regions.US_WEST_2)
        .withCryptoConfiguration(new CryptoConfiguration(CryptoMode.EncryptionOnly))
        // Can either be Key ID or alias (prefixed with 'alias/')
        .withEncryptionMaterials(new KMSEncryptionMaterialsProvider("alias/s3-kms-key"))
        .build();
```

Answer (score 0):

One does not create an encrypted bucket, but instead puts encrypted objects into the bucket.

Here is an example using Server Side Encryption (SSE):

```
AmazonS3 s3 = AmazonS3Client.standard();
s3.putObject(new PutObjectRequest()
    // this will default to AES-256...no KMS Client key used
    .withSSEAwsKeymanagementParams(new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams()) 
    // alternative if you are looking to do SSE with a Client Master Key from KMS
    //.withSSEAwsKeymanagementParams(new SSEAwsKeyManagementParams(...KMS Key Alias or ARN...)) 
    .withKey(myKey)
    .withFile(myFile));
```

Reference links:

- [AmazonS3Client#putObject](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#putObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.PutObjectRequest-)
- [PutObjectRequest#withSSEAwsKeyManagementParams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/PutObjectRequest.html#withSSEAwsKeyManagementParams-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.SSEAwsKeyManagementParams-)
- [SSEAwsKeyManagementParams](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/SSEAwsKeyManagementParams.html)

Comment: No longer true.  You can now encrypt at the bucket level.